# Processing large data chunks returned from web service into the database

Tags: php, mysql, soap

I am having trouble to process the data returned by a web service when it becomes big.
I use NuSOAP PHP library for the purpose and it all goes well when the returned data from the service is small, but when it gets bigger I reach an internal server error 500.

All I do is to use NuSOAP to retrieve the data which itself parses the results into an array and then I iterate this array to import the data into a local DDBB. Nothing fancy.
The bigger it can get is 1000 results as there is a pagination option parameter in the service which will limit to that on each call....but after 800 records or so I reach the error.

I have tried to increase the memory in the init set and increase also the execution time limit with no success.

My guess is that the problem is that the data comes at a different frequency rates that the one that php parses the data. The solution? maybe a buffer could work fine in this situation, but not sure how to achieve this in PHP.  Any thoughts?

Here is the code:

```
$client = new nusoap_client($WSDL);
do {
    $data = $client->call($serviceName, array('GetValuesFrom' => $getValuesFrom,'PW'            => $pw, 'StartIndex' => $startIndex, 'Count' => $count), $ns, $ns);

    // Check there if there are results at all
    if(!$data) {
        $message .= 'No results returned by the service<br>';
    break;
    }

    // Script that imports it to the DDBB       
    require_once('import_into_DDBB.php');

    $pulledData = count($data);
    $totalProcessed += $pulledData;
    $startIndex++;  
}
while($count == $pulledData);
```

Comment: If you get a 500 server error, you need to look into the error log of your webserver which reason is given for that error. Additionally / in parallel, enable logging with PHP as well and check that error log. Often the 500 Server error *is* a (fatal) PHP error as well. Obtain the error messages, they should give you more information what is going wrong.

Comment: You are apparently fetching `$pulledData` elements, yet `$startIndex` increments by 1 only. Doesn't this makes the system fetch again all data from 2 to `count($pulledData)-1`?

Comment: Yep, the other end is a MS Share point, and what index is are just pages. That is why I increment by 1. Page 1= from 0 to 1000, page 2= from 1001 to 2000 ...etc. Thanx for your input.

Comment: @hakre Will check the log to see if i can find out more info. thanks.